# Как перенаправить пользователя после заполнения формы?

Tags: python, django

Как перенаправить пользователя после заполнения формы в HTML-шаблон и отправить информацию из БД в данный шаблон?

Comment: Я не работал с django, но общий принцип такой:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Спасибо, Sergei Kirjanov, за полезную информацию

Answer (score 0):

[`return redirect(your_url)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/)
Можно вместо ссылки написать `name` урла на который хочешь редиректить. А что насчет получения данных из БД, можно либо редиректить на это же страницу или делать `AJAX`, про `AJAX` [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/241646/)